# Finding documents in mongodb collection where a field is equal to given integer value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I would like to find all documents where the field `property_id` is equal to -549. I tried:

```
db.getCollection('CollectionName').find({'property_id' : -549 })
```

This returns no records with a message: "Fetched 0 record(s)."

But I am seeing the document right there where the field `property_id` is -549.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The type of field is int32.

[image: Here are the first two fields of the document that I am looking to find with the query]

Comment: show us `db.getCollection('myCollectionName').find()`

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/

Comment: how do I show that? It outputs like 20 documents. You want me to take a screenshot?

Comment: copy only that document and paste in your question

Comment: try this , without quotation `db.getCollection('myCollectionName').find( { item_id : -5 } )`

Comment: @sss I added the image you asked for. 
@yash I am getting the same results when I try to run the query without quotes.
@ewcz I tried the `$eq` operator and got the same result. 

Do you think this problem is caused by  me having indexed by the field property_id

Comment: try to do this: `db.getCollection('CollectionName').find({'property_id' : {$exists: true}})` what are the results?

Comment: There's a possibility that there is a space in your field name, you may want to query with a space `db.getCollection('CollectionName').find({'property_id ' : -549 })` or `db.getCollection('CollectionName').find({' property_id' : -549 })`

Comment: Query is perfectly find there must  be some other error

Comment: It turned out there was a characterless space in my field name "property_id". It was not exactly `'property_id '` or ` 'property_id` as @chridam suggested but close. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if there is a space in the field name `'property_id'`:
Try

```
db.getCollection('CollectionName').find({'\uFEFFproperty_id' : -549 })
```